About composable metadata standard in one dapp
Can we use umi and mpltokenmetadata lib same time in one solana transaction

Sure. @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata actually is some kind of umi plugin.
E.g. if you mint a NFT using it you first set up umi, then run the mpl token metadata function:
import { generateSigner, percentAmount } from '@metaplex-foundation/umi'
import {
  createNft,
  fetchDigitalAsset,
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

const mint = generateSigner(umi)
await createNft(umi, {
  mint,
  name: 'My NFT',
  uri: 'https://example.com/my-nft.json',
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)

const asset = await fetchDigitalAsset(umi, mint.publicKey)

Source: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/getting-started/js
